# The character error when converting .dta file to .xlsx

Tags: python, stata

I have used Stata and Python (Pandas) for conversion, but encountered character errors:

```
One or more strings in the dta file could not be decoded using utf-8, and
so the fallback encoding of latin-1 is being used.  This can happen when a file
has been incorrectly encoded by Stata or some other software. You should verify
the string values returned are correct.
```

Here my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_stata("D:\STATATATATA\ho1_20.dta")

df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

I suspect it is because my .dta file is using Vietnamese language.

.My errors

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.  I think you should use ```r"D:\STATATATATA\h01_20.dta"```

Comment: thank you mate, i try but it not working i edited full traceback error